# Why can't the Style Properties of Wizard components be rendered when there is LayoutTemplate?

Tags: asp.net, wizard

Let's take the below example

http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/ASP.NET/0060__ASP.net-Controls/Customwizardnavigation.htm

It can work as normal if I just copy it without adding any code

But if I add something like this:

```
<LayoutTemplate>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="3">
                <asp:PlaceHolder ID="SideBarPlaceHolder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:PlaceHolder ID="HeaderPlaceHolder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:PlaceHolder ID="WizardStepPlaceHolder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:PlaceHolder ID="NavigationPlaceHolder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</LayoutTemplate>
```

All styles in `SideBarStyle` `HeaderStyle` `NavigationStyle` `StepStyle` won't be rendered anymore.

What's the reason behind?

Comment: but layout template does not exist on its own - is that a layout template for a listview, or some other control that you not telling us about? What is the parent control you using for the layout template? (perhaps a repeater, or maybe a listview? - you have to provide more information here.

Comment: As mentioned by the title, the parent control is `Wizard`. And all the code apart from `LayoutTemplate` can be found here [link](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/ASP.NET/0060__ASP.net-Controls/Customwizardnavigation.htm)

Comment: Ok, I'll look closer. I don't see why adding content for a step would effect the tab/side bar for this.